# How to flip the height of the li elements to go up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: h]

Can anyone help me with how to set the height of those bars to start from bottom and go up. Currently its starting from top position and going downward?
I am using javascript to generate the li elements and setting its height to some values. Here is the code:

```js
var rootContainer;
var barContainer;

var randomNumberButton;
var mergeSortButton;
const NUM_BARS = 70;

function initApp() {
  rootContainer = document.querySelector(".algo-container");
  barContainer = document.querySelector(".bar-container");

  randomNumberButton = document.getElementById("random-number");
  mergeSortButton = document.getElementById("merge-sort");

  randomNumberButton.addEventListener("click", handleRandomNumberButton);
  mergeSortButton.addEventListener("click", handleMergeSortButton);
}

function handleRandomNumberButton(e) {
  barContainer.innerHTML = "";

  let numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_BARS; i++) {
    numbers.push(generateRandomNumber(340, 100));
  }

  let ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.style.height = "100%";
  ul.style.width = "100%";

  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_BARS; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.style.backgroundColor = "#576cff";
    li.style.width = "8px";
    li.style.marginLeft = "1px";
    li.style.marginRight = "6px";
    li.style.height = `${numbers[i]}px`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  barContainer.appendChild(ul);
}

function handleMergeSortButton(e) {}

function generateRandomNumber(b, a) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (b - a) + a);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initApp);
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="algo-container"></div>
<div class="bar-container"></div>
<input id="random-number" type="button" value="Random" />
<input id="merge-sort" type="button" value="Merge - sort" />
```

Comment: Please add your code,

Comment: Next time, please click edit, the `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: So I made you a snippet. The bars DO go up in the code I guessed

Comment: all you need is vertical-align:top to li

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to the container of your stats:

```css
.container {
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

This scales the height of the container with negative one, effectively reversing it.

Alternatively you can make the container a [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) and align it's items to the bottom:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: transform: scaleY(-1); worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Rotate your container by `180deg` can do the trick. Use css transform like this on your container.

```
.your-container-class {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: This not only changes from top to bottom but also from left to right.